# SSRS 2008 display mutilple columns of data without a new line

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am creating a report in SSRS 2008 with MS SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have data based on the Aggregate value of Medical condition and the level of severity.

```
Outcome Response Adult Youth Total
BMI     GOOD     70    0     70
BMI     MONITOR  230   0     230
BMI     PROBLEM! 10    0     10
LDL     GOOD     5     0     5
LDL     MONITOR  4     0     4
LDL     PROBLEM! 2     0     2
```

I need to display the data based on the Response like:

```
      BMI   BMI     BMI
      GOOD  MONITOR PROBLEM!
Total 70    230     10
Youth 0     0       0
Adult 70    230     10

      LDL   LDL     LDL 
      GOOD  MONITOR PROBLEM!
Total 5     4       2
Youth 0     0       0
Adult 5     4       2
```

I first tried to use SSRS to do the grouping based on the Outcome and then the Response but I got each response on a separate row of data but I need all Outcomes on a single line.  I now believe that a pivot would work but all the examples I have seen is a pivot on one column of data pivoted using another.  Is it possible to pivot multiple columns of data based on a single column?

Answer (score 1):

With your existing Dataset you could so something similar to the following:

Create a **List** item, and change the **Details** grouping to be based on *Outcome*:

[image]

In the List cell, add a new **Matrix** with one **Column Group** based on *Response*:

[image]

You'll note that since you have individual columns for *Total*, *Youth*, *Adult*, you need to add grand total rows to display each group.

The end result is pretty close to your requirements:

[image]

For your underlying data, to help with report development it might be useful to have the *Total*, *Youth*, *Adult* as unpivoted columns, but it's not a big deal if the groups are fairly static.